Why is a mocked collection class not populated inside method that is tested?
I am testing a method that is populating a custom collection.
My custom collection class has a method that requires some advanced stuff that is not important for my test, so I tried to mock the collection object to setup a mock for that method. The custom collection is input parameter to the method I am testing, so I send in the mocked object as input.
This seems to work up to the point where elements are added to the collection. The Add method runs, but the collection is not updated and Count is still 0.
Why is not the elements added to the mocked collection object?
Here is a simplified setup of my code:
class MyClass {
    private string _item;
    public MyClass(string item) {
        _item = item;
    }
}

class MyCollectionClass : Collection<MyClass> {
    public string ApplyEdits() {
        // Some advanced stuff that is not important for test
        return "Actual value";
    }
}

class ClassToBeTested {
    public int MethodToBeTested(MyCollectionClass myCollection, string[] items) {
        items.ForEach(item => {
            var myItem = new MyClass(item);
            myCollection.Add(myItem);
            // When running the test, this should have updated Count on the collection, but it doesn't
        });
            // After populate, this method is executed, but it is not important for test:
        myCollection.ApplyEdits();
        return myCollection.Count;
    }
}

And the test:
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest() {
        var mock = new Mock<MyCollectionClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.ApplyEdits()).Returns("dummy");

        var classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();

        var items = new List<string>();
        // Populate items
        items.Add("test1");
        items.Add("test2");
        items.Add("test3");

        var result = classToBeTested.MethodToBeTested(mock.Object, items.ToArray());
        Assert.AreEqual(items.Count, result);

}

So I guess the question is really - how can I make the Add method actually add items to the mocked collection object when called inside MethodToBeTested?

provide a [mcve]

The mocked class does only what you told it to do and this is returning the string "dummy" when calling ApplyEdits. It will do nothing else.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, calling ApplyEdits() will do what I told it to, but why does not Add(item) actually add item to the collection object? I have not overridden Add method in the mock setup...

The mocked class is not inheriting anything, it is just providing a minimal implementation of the "interface" you specified (which happens to be a class in your case but usually you would specify a C# interface here). Unless you specified behaviors (as you did for ApplyEdits), all the methods and properties will be empty or return default values.

I think you are looking for partial mock. In this case you have to explicitly say that I want to override these and the remaining methods should do their original logic. new Mock<MyCollectionClass>() { CallBase = true }

In this case maybe the mock could be omitted and real instance of the class MyCollectionClass could be passed, where only the functionality for the Some advanced stuff that is not important for test could actually be mocked?
